# Задачка по C++ по форматированию чисел в текст

Tags: c++

Изучаю C++, столкнулся со следующей задачей.
Увы, в голове только слишком замороченный и объемный алгоритм, а мне обязательно нужен максимально простой и короткий.

> Задача: Создайте исходный код, который преобразует числа от -999999 до 9999 в текст на англ. языке (Совет: Воспользуйтесь тем, что переменные целого типа округляют числа, отбрасывая знаки после десятичной запяток. Помните, что ваш алгоритм не обязан быть универсальным - он должен работать с числами, состоящими не более чем из шести цифр.)

Comment: Я тут тоже столкнулся с задачей, клиенту нужно сделать алгоритм и программу, как правильно рассчитать диаметр турбины и там еще некоторые параметры, что бы она не разлеталась от вибраций и к.п.д. был максимальным. Давайте так, я Вам делаю программу преобразования чисел в английский текст, а Вы мне программу оптимального расчета турбины. Да, клиент готов платить твердой валютой (золотом).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS

#include <stdio.h>

char * place[] = {"", " thousand ", " million ", " billion ", " trillion "};
char * _1_9[] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine"};
char * _10_19[] = {"ten", "eleven", "twelve", "thirteen", "fourteen", "fifteen", "sixteen", "seventeen", "eighteen", "nineteen"};
char * _20_90[] = {"twenty", "thirty", "forty", "fifty", "sixty", "seventy", "eighty", "ninety"};

void spell_number(int n, int poz) {
    /*знак*/
    if(n < 0) {
        printf("minus ");
        n = -n;
    }

    /*преобразуем старшие разряды числа*/
    if(n / 1000)
        spell_number(n / 1000, poz + 1);

    /*преобразуем сотни в слова*/
    n%=1000;//сотни
    if(n / 100) 
        printf("%s hundred ", _1_9[n / 100 - 1]);

    /*преобразуем десятки в слова (или сразу единицы)*/
    n %= 100;
    if(n / 10) {
        if(n < 20)
            printf("%s", _10_19[n - 10]);
        else {
            printf("%s", _20_90[n / 10 - 2]);
            if(n % 10)
                printf(" %s", _1_9[n % 10 - 1]);
        }
    }else
        printf("%s", _1_9[n - 1]);

    if(poz<sizeof(place))
        printf("%s",place[poz]);
    else
        printf(" err ");
}


int main() {
    int n;
    if(scanf("%d", &n)) {
        spell_number(n,0);
    }

    return 0;
}
```